# What is the format name of this data?

Tags: java, parsing, format

Short: I'd like to know the name of this format!

I would like to know if this is a special common format or just a simple self-generated config file:

```
scenes : {
  Scene : {
    class : Scene
    sources : {
      Game Capture : {
        render : 1
        class : GraphicsCapture
        data : {
          window : "[duke3d]: Duke Nukem 3D Atomic Edition 1.4.3 STABLE"
          windowClass : SDL_app
          executable : duke3d.exe
          stretchImage : 0
          alphaBlend : 0
          ignoreAspect : 0
          captureMouse : 1
          invertMouse : 0
          safeHook : 0
          useHotkey : 0
          hotkey : 123
          gamma : 100
        }
        cx : 1920
        cy : 1080
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My background is, that I would like to read multiple files like this one above. And I don't want to implement a whole new parser for this. That's why I want to fall back on java libraries which have already implemented this feature. But without being aware of such code formats, it's quite difficult to search for this libraries.

// additional info

- This is a config file or a "scene file" for Open Broadcaster Software.
- Filename extension is .xconfig

Comment: With a little effort, you can make JSON out of it. Just automate inserting commas in appropriate places, then use a JSON parser.

Comment: That's actually what i like to prevent. i just want to use 3.api libraries to parse it without pre-formating the data.

Comment: I'd like to know what kind of format this is and search for a library by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some feedback from the main developer of this files.

As i thought, this is not a know format - just a simple config file.

solved!

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a config file or a "scene file" for Open Broadcaster Software.
When used with OBS it has a extension of .xconfig
Hope this helps.
-Yang

Comment: Indeed, thats a xconfig file from obs. and i like to parse it into a external application. i'm aware of this. thx